# htaccess redirect based on a block of URL parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters, block

I'm trying to do a htaccess redirect based on a parameter in de URL. Sounds simple but my problem is this: a block of parameters I want to go to the left and the rest to the right.

The example:

Current URL (not existent): http: www.schedjoules.com/102657832.html
Desired URL: http: www.schedjoules.com/us/102657832.html

Everyhting between 102633352 and 102657832 I want to direct to www.schedjoules.com/us/ and everything else to www.schedjoules.com/en/

The best rewrite I can think of is 
`RewriteRule ^/([102633352-102657832])\.html$ http://www.schedjoules.com/us/$1\.html [R=301,L]`

but it is doesn't work (500 error). I have read half the internet but can't find a solution. Is there a way to redirect by a block of parameters?

Rutger

Comment: Why don't you use a PHP script?

Comment: I use RoR but not a bad thought at all. Never thought of that. Thanks. But is it possible to do this kind of stuff in htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Your rule is completely wrong: `[102633352-102657832]`

The square brackets mean a character class - matches one of the characters. You have repeated the same characters multiple times (e.g. `1`, `0` etc) + you have a range character `-` describing invalid range (can be from lower to higher `1-2` not `2-1`).

In any case -- these rules will do the job:

```
RewriteCond $1 >102633351
RewriteCond $1 <102657833
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.html$ http://www.schedjoules.com/us/$1\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.html$ http://www.schedjoules.com/en/$1\.html [R=301,L]
```

1. [Lexicographical comparison](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) was used (`<` and `>`)
2. Because comparison is not numeric but rather by character, the numbers have been changed (-1/+1 accordingly) otherwise the edge numbers would fail.
3. These rules will redirect files within a range to `/us/` subfolder and ALL OTHER NUMBERS to `/en/`.